# Are there any HTML5/Canvas windowing system libraries (ala Qt, WxWidgets, etc)?

Tags: javascript, qt, html, canvas

With the beginning of widespread HTML5 support and Canvas support, it seems that someone could create a desktop-esque windowing system library for RIAs.  Something similar to Qt or WxWidgets.  All the required parts seem to be there (runtime language: javascript, pixel drawing: canvas, even vector drawing with SVGs).

This seems to me anyway that it could be a huge leap for the ease of development of RIAs.  Forget about classic HTML and styling, and simply create widgets like you would in a desktop application.

I have been searching around on the web for quite a while though and can't find anything that jumps out at me as fitting this description.  Am I missing something or is there just nothing like this out there yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/) and [Capuccino](http://www.cappuccino-project.org/).